# How to create a twitter bot that replies back as soon as another person tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, anaconda, bots, tweepy

Yesterday I wrote a twitter bot with Python that takes the most recent tweet from Donald Trump, translates it over in Google Translate 45 times, and tweets back at him the final translation in English. Everything works, except the fact that I now need to add some sort of "listener" at the beginning of the code to automatically detect when he tweets so that the rest of the code can do its magic. I've been looking over the internet for some time now and I can't seem to find any sort of event handler that would allow the script to detect when he tweets. So that's why I've come to you guys. Is there any way to use Tweepy or other Python libraries to actively detect when someone tweets? I'll include my code so you guys can see what I want to happen exactly when he does Tweet. It's annotated so hopefully it's not too complicated to understand. Thanks!

```py
import tweepy
from googletrans import Translator

#Keys for accessing the Twitter API

consumer_key = 'PLACEHOLDER'
consumer_secret = 'PLACEHOLDER'
access_token = 'PLACEHOLDER'
access_token_secret = 'PLACEHOLDER'

#Setting up authentification

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Scrapes my timeline for DT's latest tweet. I want this to be done AUTOMATICALLY when he tweets.

tweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'realDonaldTrump', count = 1, include_rts = False, tweet_mode = 'extended')

#Translates the text from the .json file that is pulle from the previous line using the Google translate library.

for status in tweet:
    translator = Translator()
    translation = translator.translate(translation.text, 'mn')
    translation = translator.translate(status._json["full_text"], 'ja')

#There are more translations in the actual code, but to reduce the length and complexity, I've taken those out. They don't matter to the specific question.   

#Include his handle in a message so that the tweet is tweeted back at him once the translation is complete.

message = ('@realDonaldTrump', translation.text)

#Tweets the message back at him under that specific tweet using it's ID.

send = api.update_status(message, status._json["id"])
```

I just want the code to be able to scrape my timelines for one of DT's tweets in real time. Thanks!

Comment: 1. check most recent tweet from him 2. compare the date to the date of tweet in the last check 3. if date is greater tweet else do nothing 4. schedule this to run every X seconds/minutes/days

Comment: this will be against Twitter’s automation rules, so is likely to be write-restricted very quickly for automated and unsolicited replies or mentions https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation

Comment: Since Twitter updated its automation rules, you will not able to do that on mass level. However 1 or 2 tweets every hour may work but may be restricted to perform write actions.

Answer (score 0):

To Automate your script, you might need to push it into a production server and then create a cron job that will run the script at given regular intervals. To run it locally, I use 1. NGROK - Exposes your localhost addresses and ports to the outside world ie it gives you a way to reach your localhost from the internet, and 2. Invictify - This allows you to run your scripts at a schedule. Also, the script as it is will need a web service to be triggered. Use Flask or FastAPI to create endpoints that call the script when triggered.